# Is there a NOT operator in VSCode Keybindings JSON to invert an entire "when" clause?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding, not-operator

The "when" clause in VSCode's JSON keybindings editor is very useful, but I can't seem to find a way to reverse it. For instance, if I want an action to only work when the Terminal view is not showing, I would want something like this:
`"when": "not.terminalViewShowing"`
or
`"when.not": "terminalViewShowing"`

Is something like this possible and if not, are there any plans to add it?

Answer (score 2):

If the when clause only contains one condition, then you can just invert that single condition with the `!` operator. For the current list of operators in when-clauses, see the official docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#conditional-operators.

If the when clause contains multiple condition joined by logical operators...

See this GitHub issue: [Add support for parenthesis in "when" conditions #91473](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91473), which was added to [VS Code's March 2023 Milestone](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/218), and was closed as completed by the [context keys: implement a new parser (and a scanner/lexer) for 'when' clauses #174471](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/174471) pull request. So you can just wrap your when clause with `!(...)`. You can read about the exact syntax and grammar there. Here's a quote of its syntax and grammar in [Extended Backus-Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form):

> ```
> expression ::= or
>
> or ::= and { '||' and }*
>
> and ::= term { '&&' term }*
>
> term ::=
>   | '!' (KEY | 'true' | 'false')
>   | primary
>
> primary ::=
>   | 'true'
>   | 'false'
>   | '(' expression ')'
>   | KEY '=~' REGEX
>   | KEY [ ('==' | '!=' | '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' | 'not' 'in' | 'in') value ]
>
> value ::=
>   | 'true'
>   | 'false'
>   | 'in'     
>   | KEY
>   | SINGLE_QUOTED_STR
>   | EMPTY_STR
> ```

See also the announcement / discussion issue ticket for the new feature: [Upcoming when clause context parser
#175540](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175540).

<sup>Fun note: Even before parenthesis support in when clauses got added, you could usually use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) as a workaround to negate when-clauses.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as adding the `!` before your `terminalViewShowing`.

```
"when": "!terminalViewShowing"
```

BYW, parentheses are not supported in `when` clauses, see [Add support for parenthesis in "when" conditions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91473)https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91473 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147904.

---

Update: A PR has just been merged that introduces a new parser for `when` clauses which does, finally, support parentheses, see [context keys: implement a new parser (and a scanner/lexer) for 'when' clauses](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/174471).